# different answers in r2007b and r2012b

Tags: matlab

```
num = 10 ; 
den = [1 2 10] ; 
stepsize = 0.00001 ; 

g = tf(num,den) ; 
t = 0:stepsize:5 ;
y = step(g,t) ;

figure(1) ;

plot(t,y) ; 
iter = size(t,2) ; 

for i = 1:iter-1
    if( y(i+1) < y(i) )
        peak = y(i) ; 
        peaktime = i*stepsize ; 
        break ;
    end
end

fprintf('%20s : %.4f\n','Peak',peak );
fprintf('%20s : %.4f\n','Peaktime',peaktime);
```

I ran this code in my college's department lab which has MATLAB r2007 installed there i got the value of `Peak` to be `1.3489` but on my own system which has r2012b , I ran this same code and got value of `Peak` to be `1.3509` .

Can anyone brief me about why this discrepancy is occuring ?

PS : This program just finds the peak and peaktime of the step-response of the given transfer function which in this case is

```
                                     10
                               --------------
                               s^2 + 2*s + 10
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'd like to run equivalent code in another language and see what I get. The only function that isn't obvious to me is line 5, `tf(num,den)`. What does that do?

Comment: i would imagine its something to do with floating point precision , But not sure if anything has changed by default

Comment: It creates the transfer function using num and den

Comment: By the way, `[~,peak,peaktime]=overshoot(y,t);` is a much simple way of finding what you're looking for. It returns The latter value, `1.3509`, on R2013a. Maybe they changed something in how `step` is evaluated. Type `edit step` in your command window and compare the code for the two versions.

Comment: thanks a lot @horchler i didn't know that we could look at the code of the in-built functions, that was a lot of help